# free lightweight mobile webmail

Tags: email, mobile, looking-for-a-script, webmail

I'm looking for a free lightweight mobile webmail.

Something like squirrelmail but for mobile phones.

roberto

Comment: For what operating system and which phone? Android, iOS, blackberry?

Answer (score 3):

I would open a Gmail account, make it pull email from the service provider where email is stored and use Gmail's mobile application to read email.

Not the best of solutions, but the fastest one.

Answer (score 0):

If your question meant which software package can you install on your site?
Well there used to be a [gmail mobile project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gmail-mobile/) which you could run on your own server.

Here are some squirrelmail alternatives: (free)

- [nasmail.org](http://www.nasmail.org/)
- [roundcube.net](http://www.roundcube.net)
- [neomail.org](http://sourceforge.net/projects/neomail/)

Other:

- [banckle email](http://banckle.com/apps/email-server/default.html)

---

I tried to aggregate this requirement that roberto had onto my site:

- [m.defza.com/email](http://m.defza.com/email/)

Here are some lightweight free email providers:

- [m.gmail.com](http://m.gmail.com/)
- [m.yahoo.com](http://m.yahoo.com)
- [mail.ovi.com](http://mail.ovi.com/)
- [mail.live.com](http://mail.live.com) or [mobile.msn.com](http://mobile.msn.com)

There were a few more at one stage, but the overhead of providing free email along with the spam problem meant that most providers had to shutdown.  This means that only the best of the best will survive, gmail, hotmail, yahoo - these have proven to stand the test of time.
Even now Nokia's [Ovi Mail is been run by Yahoo](http://blog.ovi.com/2010/11/06/mail-and-chat-soon-to-be-powered-by-yahoo/).